# Adding Rows Dynamically using Javascript

Tags: javascript

Here I am adding rows dynamically in table when user clicks "AddNewRow" button.
Here is the code for adding rows dynamilly,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function addRow() {

            var table = document.getElementById("modaltable"); //Table ID
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
            var colCount = table.rows[1].cells.length;

            for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
                var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
                newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
                //alert(newcell.childNodes);
                switch (newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
                    case "Comment":
                        newcell.childNodes[i].value = "";
                        break;
                    case "DropDownList2":
                        newcell.childNodes[i].selectedIndex = 0;
                        break;
                    case "DropDownList1":
                        newcell.childNodes[i].selectedIndex = 0;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
      </script>
```

Button code for adding rows.
Add New Row

When I click "Addnewrow" button it will add another row dynamically. But here it is adding the row but row is taking the first row value as default. But I don't need first row selected values in another rows. Any mistake in the above code.

Comment: Please provide an example with your HTML.

Comment: Instead of *insetRow* and *insertCell*, consider just cloning the row and traversing over the cells: `var row = table.rows[0].cloneNode(true);`, iterate over `row.cells`, then `table.appendChild(row)`.

Answer (score 0):

The new rows value is repeated because of this line

`newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;`

new cell value is copied from existing rows cell value.

so just refer to this line to update the new rows cell value, like this

`newcell.innerHTML = 'newVal'+(i+1)`;

[Live Demo @ JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4ry63twv/)

Comment: newcell.innerHTML = 'newVal'+(i+1);                                                                            here in place of 'newVal' which variable I need to pass. Because it is displaying the text as it is.

Comment: @kiran: that was just for reference. well you can pass the cell text to `addRow('roger')`, and include the same to new rows cell . check this for reference , https://jsfiddle.net/4ry63twv/2/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need first row selected values in the new dynamically generated rows, you need to replace the following code:

```
newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
```

with

```
newcell.innerHTML = "";
```